# Can't remove place holders with regular expression in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a dynamically created table containing some redundant place holders that I would like to remove, they look like this:

```
{firm[i][j]} //i,j are numbers
```

I am trying regular expression in JavaScript but it doesn't work, here is my regular expression, table below is a string which will be inserted into DOM.

```
var table = "

<table class='table table-sm' style='margin:auto;'>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th colspan='5'>QARELEASE</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr style='text-align:left;'>
        <td width='25%;'>{firm[i][j]}</td>
        <td width='25%;'>{firm[i][j]}</td>
        <td width='25%;'>{firm[i][j]}</td>
        <td width='25%;'>{firm[i][j]}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>

</table>"
```

regular expression:

```
table = table.replace(/{firm[\d{1}][\d{1}]}/g, "");
```

Not quite sure why it couldn't work

Comment: What's `table`? Show all the relevant code.

Comment: Are you trying to match [ ] literally? if so you need to escape them.

Comment: I assume that even the curly braces might have to be escaped: `/\{firm\[\d{1}\]\[\d{1}\]\}/g`

Comment: you want to replace _x_  to " ". what is _x_ btw?

Comment: The `{1}` quantifiers are superfluous.

Comment: Sorry guys, I forgot to give the table code, updated the question

Comment: Thanks guys, @Matus is right, I need to escape [] too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to match [] too, you will need to escape them:

```
table = table.replace(/{firm\[\d{1}\]\[\d{1}\]}/g, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

another direct approach is to return from capturing groups like below:

```
var str = '{firm[123][12]}'; 
str.replace(/\{firm\[(\d+)\]\[(\d+)\]\}/g,"$1,$2") //will return 123,12
str.replace(/\{firm\[(\d+)\]\[(\d+)\]\}/g,"{foo $1-$2}") // will return {foo 123,12}
//and so on ....
```